# Enviar dados de um formulário para uma URL

Tags: html, formulário

Conheço de html, mas não sou expert. Criei um site para minha pousada com base em um template que adquiri na themeforrest e nele tem um form que recebe dados (como entrada, saida, adultos, etc)

o formulário é o seguinte:

```
<!--Book Section-->
<section class="book-section">
    <div class="auto-container">

        <div class="row clearfix">

            <!--Title Column-->
            <div class="title-column col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="bg-layer"></div>
                <!--Inner Box-->
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <h2>RESERVE</h2>
                    <div class="text">Melhor Preço Garantido</div>
                    <!--Arrow Box-->
                    <div class="arrow-box"><span class="icon fa fa-angle-right"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Form Column-->
            <div class="form-column col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <form method="post" action="contact.html">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="column col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="clearfix">


                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="group-inner">
                                            <label>Check In</label>
                                            <input type="date" name="in" value="" placeholder="Entrada" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="group-inner">
                                            <label>Check Out</label>
                                            <input type="date" name="out" value="" placeholder="Saída" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="group-inner">
                                            <label>Adultos</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="adultos" value="" placeholder="Adultos" min="1" max="4" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="group-inner">
                                            <label>Crianças</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="child" value="" placeholder="Crianças" min="0" max="3">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--Avalability Column-->
                            <div class="avalability-column col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://hbook.hsystem.com.br/Booking?companyId=593ec639c19a3b40b852aaec">
                                <button type="submit">
                                    <span class="big-txt">Reservar agora</span>
                                    <span class="small-text">Checar disponibilidade</span>
                                </button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</section>
<!--End Book Section-->
```

Estou trabalhando com uma empresa de reservas online e preciso passar os dados desse formulário para a URL do site dessa empresa. Por exemplo:

> https://reservas/booking?companyId=COMPANY_ID&adults=2&checkin=2017-09-07&checkout=2017-09-10

O companyId é fixo, e não é passado pelo formulário. Mas o *checkin* e *checkout*, por exemplo, precisariam receber valores diferentes a partir desse formulário para cada cliente diferente.

Qual a melhor maneira de proceder? Atualmente estou redirecionando direto para a URL de reservas online, sem passar os parâmetros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu HTML os `input's` tem que ter os atributos `name` como a página que vai receber os dados espera. O `companyId` deve ficar num `input` com `type="hidden"`.

A página vai receber os parâmetros pelo método `get`, então pode usar esse formulário como exemplo e adequar ao seu código:

```
<form action="https://reservas/booking" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="companyId" value="COMPANY_ID">
    Adultos: <select name="adults">
        <option value="1">1</option>        
        <option value="2">2</option>        
    </select>
    Check-in: <input type="date" name="checkin">
    Check-out <input type="date" name="checkout">
    <input type="submit" value="Consultar Disponibilidade">
</form>
```

> Substitua o `COMPANY_ID` no código pelo seu ID.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o

```
<form method=get action=pagina.php(sem o resto do link)>
```

E crie inputs com name = nome_do_campo
Exemplo:

```
<input name=ADULT type=text>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Fernando Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.